# How to access the display property of a row inside a html table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html table populated by sql, in a php file something like this:

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <tr> <th>Name</th><th>Weight</th> </tr>
     <tbody id='budy'>
      <tr>
        <td> x </td><td> 3 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> y </td><td> 9 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> x </td><td> 1 kg</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> x </td><td> 6 kg</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> y </td><td> 7 kg</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

And this filter function to search either the name or the weight across the table:

```
function doSearch() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById('filterInput').value;
    var targetTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var btn=document.getElementById("totalbtn");
    var targetTableColCount;
    document.getElementById("totalbtn").disabled=false;
    //Loop through table rows
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++ ) {
         var rowData = '';
         //Get column count from header row
          if (rowIndex == 0) {
              targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
              continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
            }
           var rowCells = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells;
           for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < 2; colIndex++) {
                var cellText = '';

                if (targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex)) {                      
                    cellText = rowCells.item(colIndex)[(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet 
                            Explorer')? "innerText" : "textContent"];
                 }
                   rowData += cellText;
            }

             // Make search case insensitive.
            rowData = rowData.toLowerCase();
            searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

            //If search term is not found in row data
            //then hide the row, else show
            if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
                 targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
              else
                  targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
            }
        }
```

I understand the function, but i am not the one who programmed it, my question is how can i access  just the rows left(which i believe have the html property 'display!= none') after the user input text in the text filter? i have tried with:

```
  function sum(){
      var buttoncal = document.getElementById("totalbtn");
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var sum=0;
      var temp;
     for(var i=1; i< table.rows.length; i++){
          sum = sum + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML.slice(0,1));
          temp=table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML.slice(0,1)
          console.log(temp);
      }
    }
```

but so far i only get the sum of all rows, including the one with the "new" display property of 'none' instead of just adding the rows shown after the filter is used.
Thanks for any advice to solve this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to select all rows which have `display="none"` so you can extract the `innerHTML` property of the cell in index position `2`?

Comment: All the way around i want to select all rows that do not have the property display="none" so i can add just the value of the cell the position 2 (which is the weight's integer) and show it on a <span> or a <tr>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search function is already distinguishing between rows that are hidden (`display="none"`) and rows that are `display="table-row"` so you can use that logic to do your sum:

```
function doSearch() {
  let sum = 0;

  // ...

  // Replace your display='none'/display='table-row' logic with:
  if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1) {
    targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
    sum += parseInt( targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells[1] );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir ! is amazing how a different point of view can give a direct solution, but i had to add the ".innerHTML.slice(0,1)" at the end of  "sum += parseInt( targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells[1] );" because it was giving me a NaN as result, but also you made me spot a huge mistake in my logic, since i "slice" the first alphanumeric in the "innnerHTML" it will not count when it has 2 or 3 digits, is there a function like explode (php) or the sql "like" command to use here and for example just get the numbers before the 'kg'? Thanks again.

Comment: @Dupo There's no need to manually extract the number from the string because `parseInt()` will stop when it reaches the first non-numeric character. But if you want to do it as an exercise, you can either use something like `.trim().split(' ')[0]`. So the full code would be `targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells[1].trim().split(' ')[0]`. This will trim any leading/trailing spaces (to give you e.g. '12 kg'), then split the remaining string along spaces, giving you an array (`['12', 'kg']`), and `[0]` will give you the first element ('12').

Comment: yes i found the split function and did something similar, and add sum the lines of code with only the numerical element , thanks again for taking the time to explain and give an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) row element instead setting display to `none`

```
if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
   targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).remove()
else
   targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
```

it will delete element from DOM, so you cant return it back

Comment: That doesn't let you display them again when the search text changes, since you have deleted them entirely. Also, because you have deleted the row at `rowIndex`, the next row is now also at `rowIndex`, but since the loop's `rowIndex++` will skip this next row, you need to also `rowIndex--`.